# jQuery replace HTML in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace

I want to replace following HTML string:

```
</p><span onclick="alert(event)" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" contenteditable="false">XXX</span><p><br></p>
```

with:

```
</p><button onclick="alert(event)" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" contenteditable="false">YYY</button><p><br></p>
```

using jQuery. I have tried `.replace()` function, but its not working for some strange reason.

Comment: Where is your code that fails?

Comment: You start with ... </p>

Comment: @HasH: please do not make edits to add `code formatting` to proper nouns like HTML and jQuery. They are not code, and should not be formatted as such. Adding whole sentences is bold is not obviously a readability improvement either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/bqfv5fge/1/

```js
var span = $('span:contains("XXX")');
span.after('<button>YYY</button>');


$(span[0].attributes).each(function() {
    $('button:contains("YYY")').prop(this.nodeName, this.nodeValue);
});

span.remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span onclick="alert(event)" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" contenteditable="false">XXX</span><p>
test paragraph
</p>
```

Use `jQuery` `contains` to get the target element.

**Reference Document:** https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

First get the reference of `span` element, then add `button` next to span using `jQuery` `after`.

Then attach all the `attribute` to the `button` and then remove `span`.

Answer (score 2):

try give span an ID and
You can do:

```
$("#yourid").text("YYY");
```

or

```
$("#yourID").html("testing <b>YYY</b>");
```

Comment: The input is a string, and the `span` tag needs to change as well.

Comment: Put the span into a div with Id and then change the content as mentioned above from phpdroid

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but better to add an ID for selector.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('span').click(function(){
    $(this).text('YYY') or $(this).html('YYY');
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var attr ='';
$("span").each(function(){
 $.each(this.attributes,function(){
   attr += this.name+'="'+this.value+'"';
  });
});

$("span").replaceWith('<button '+attr+'>'+$('span').text()+'</button>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span onclick="alert(event)" class="btn btn-sm btn-success xyz" contenteditable="false">XXX</span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s0bv09gm/.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to replace "span" with "button" tag:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var x = '</p><span onclick="alert(event)" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" contenteditable="false">XXX</span><p><br></p>';
alert(x.replace(/span/g,"button"));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L26fvfvL/

If you want to replace XXX with YYY:

HTML Code:

```
<span onclick="alert(event)" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" contenteditable="false">XXX</span>
```

JQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x = $("span");
    x.html(x.html().replace("XXX","YYY"));
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f7qsa6kw/

If you want to do both the things, apply the second step and then first step.